# Need some clarification about singleton pattern

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

Does singleton design pattern make sure one single object reference or there is any chance/possibility of more then one ref of an object while implementing singleton pattern, I think in the case of multi threading there is a some chance of more then one object even we have implemented singleton pattern.

Please help.

Comment: It depends on the implementation - in case of a broken implementation, chances are that multithread environment causes problems. The pattern itself has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for threading to cause problems with a singleton. You can find a comprehensive set of solutions for making singletons thread safe here:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. If an instance already exists, it simply returns a reference to that object. However in a multithreaded environment it is possible that 2 separate threads may enter `getInstance()` simultaneously, check that instance is `null` and then create 2 instances of the class. Hence in order to prevent it you need to mark your `getInstance()` as `synchronized` as in:

```
public static synchronized Singletone getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new createInstance();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061328/singleton-class-in-java-api) post for a better understanding .

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern ensures a single object is created in an application running on a JVM. This holds true even in Multithreaded environment. If not, that's not Singleton or at least badly programmed Singleton.

Answer (score -1):

When you have singleton class, you can't create more then one object of that class. You may create many reference on that object, but object will be same.